# Visual Studio options greyed out?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I'm working on a ASP.NET Web Application project, and I'm unable to add a web form to application. The "Add Item" menu item isn't there like it was before. I've tried three different projects and it keeps happening each time. You can see what I'm referring to below:

[image]

Comment: Stupid question (and not trying to insult intelligence), but you're not currently in the middle of a debug/build are you?

Comment: wow, i'm insanely stupid for that. thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was in the middle of a debug (thanks Brad Christie) so if anyone has that problem, that's the likely solution.

Comment: Not a problem. Saw "Maryland" as your locations and figured the eastern time zone had _some_ effect. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

**Publish option greyed out**

For me, the project I was trying to publish needed to be selected in the project explorer before the publish option became available.

**Why put this answer here?**

Google sent me here even though I was specifically searching for the Publish option.  If it sends other developers here, perhaps this answer may be useful.